# How to create configuration for a controller manually so I can use a generic try catch function

Tags: c#, generics

I currently have the below code which I thought would work however I am receiving a "HttpControllerContext.Configuration must not be null" error when I create the Ok result. The goal is to be able to call any function in a controller in one line to keep my controllers clean. Such as "`return ApiUtilities.TryCatch(() => _someService.Get(id));`"
I only have access to '`Ok()`', "`NotFound()`" and "`InternalServerError()`" because the `ApiUtilities` Class inherits from `ApiController`

```
public IHttpActionResult TryCatch<T>(Func<T> operation)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = operation();

            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
catch (Exception error)
{
    return InternalServerError();
}
```

Edit: 
My controller looks like this

```
public class PageController : ApiController
    {
        private ISomeService _someService;
        private ApiUtilities _apiUtilities;
        public PageController(ISomeService someService)
        {
            _someService= someService;
            _apiUtilities = new ApiUtilities();
        }

        [Route("api/page")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get([FromBody]string url)
        {
           return _apiUtilities.TryCatch(() =>  _someService.Get(url));
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling the action method? This helper method wouldn't cause the issue you are seeing.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082239/c-sharp-webapi-provider-ihttpactionresult-in-class-library). Specifically the part of the answer that reads "Do not inherit from ApiController as this is instantiated by a factory in the request pipeline. You should only inherit it for actual api controller instances, not for convenience of some of the existing methods. "

Comment: Since you newed up the `ApiUtilities` yourself, it has no context and cannot process the `Ok`, `BadRequest`, etc methods, If you look at the answer in the linked question, you can see that they use the result constructors (ie `BadResultRequest`), passing in the controller to use its context

Answer (score 0):

Below is the update I've made based on a Friend's suggestion. I've removed the inheritance on the ApiController. I've also returned the same models the `Ok`, `BadRequest` and `NotFound` functions generate using the context of the current api.

```
public static class ApiUtilities
    {
        public static IHttpActionResult TryCatch(Action action, ApiController apiController)
        {
            try
            {
                if (apiController.ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    action();

                    return new OkResult(apiController);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new BadRequestResult(apiController);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                return new NotFoundResult(apiController);
            }
        }
        public static IHttpActionResult TryCatch<T>(Func<T> operation, ApiController apiController)
        {
            try
            {
                if (apiController.ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var result = operation();

                    return new OkNegotiatedContentResult<T>(result, apiController);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new BadRequestResult(apiController);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                return new NotFoundResult(apiController);
            }
        }
    }
```